# Google spreadsheets with php. Get or export data from sheets with limited access

Tags: php, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client, google-authentication

Hi all and sorry for my bad English. My task was to get data from sheets (tables) Google docs.

I export data from Google docs using URL with params:

https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=[file_id_here]&exportFormat=csv

Retrieve data from the file has no problem, but then I found out, that the real lists are restricted and this is where the problems started.

Instead of CSV file, Google returns authorization.

My question is how to organize the connection to `Google api with token client` if the client has the right of access to the document, the document data is displayed , otherwise, "You do not have permission to view the document!" message appears. OR  Maybe it is possible to add parameter(client token) to URL, though this is not possible.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you need to use  Oauth2 and have the owner of the file authenticate.

Comment: Thanks and thanks for edit my question.